# Issues after connecting hbase from Tableau with Simba driver

Tags: string, hbase, tableau-api, simba

After connceting to hbase with Simba driver,most of the measures are visible in String format in Tableau though they are loaded as integer from hbase end,what might be the reason?Though I am converting measures from strings to decimal format in Tableau,incorrect values are being obtained.What is the resolution?

Answer (score 1):

This is because HBase exposes data as bytes, so the ODBC driver cannot determine the true format of the data. You can use the schema editor in the HBase driver to change the schema that the driver detects so it's appropriate for your data. By default, the driver tries to guess the type but since it doesn't have much information, this usually requires some tweaking.

See http://cdn.simba.com/products/Hbase/doc/Simba_HBase_ODBC_InstallGuide.pdf, page 12 for how to define the schema.